# How add custom font icon from unicode value in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

How to use custom font from unicode value in objective c?

I am using this code but couldn't able to show the proper icon.

```
[_lblShow setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"icomoon" size:150]];
  NSString *str=[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"\uef99"] ;
[_lblShow setText:str];
```

Comment: Have you included the relevant ttf files?

Comment: yes. i use the custom font use **fontello.com** and create own ttf. and and use in objective c

Comment: Thanks for give suggestion @ Works On Mine

Comment: According to http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ef99/index.htm , the character that you are trying to display is not a valid unicode character. It could also be that the font that you are using, doesnt support that character.